# How do I sum the items in a php loop?

Tags: php, loops

I've been learning PHP for a few days and I have an embarrassingly easy question. I want to sum the items in a 500 item loop. I want to figure out the total of 500 + 499 + 498, etc.

Here's my code:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=500; $i++)
{

 // echo $i . "<br />";
 $total = 0;
 $total = $total + $i;
 return $total;


}

echo $total . "<br />";

?>
```

Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Pull out the initialization and the return statement from the loop:

```
$total = 0;

for ($i=1; $i<=500; $i++) {

    echo $i . ""; 
    $total = $total + $i; 

}

echo $total . "";
return $total;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also do

```
echo array_sum(range(0,500)); // 125250
```

or do the entire calculation without a `for` body:

```
for( $total = $i = 0; $i <= 500; $total += $i++ );
echo $total;  // 125250
```

and a couple of other approaches ([Daniel's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288622/how-do-i-sum-the-items-in-a-php-loop/4288634#4288634) is particularly nice).

Both of the above are equivalent to what you are likely looking for

```
$total = 0;
for ($i=1; $i<=500; $i++) {
    $total = $total + $i;
}
echo $total;
```

Like already pointed out elsewhere, when you do  `$total = 0;` inside the [`for` loop](http://de.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php), you will overwrite the previous value for `$total` and putting [`return`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) into it will end your script unless the loop is inside a function.

Comment: I think they're trying to use this as a simple example to learn loops, not to actually accomplish the task at hand.  Useful nonetheless +1

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I'm not there yet in my PHP learning. I hope I will be soon

Comment: Good answer... but the OP could also do that in O(1) instead of in O(n) by finding the [sum of an arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you simply need to move the `$total = 0;` line out of your loop... Otherwise it will be set to `0` on each iteration.

You also need to move that `return $total;` line outside, as [@Webnet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/197606/webnet) noted in a comment below.

Also note that you can do that calculation in [constant time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_time#Constant_time) without iterating through all the numbers, by finding the [sum of an arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum):

> S<sub>n</sub> = <sup>1</sup>/<sub>2</sub>n(a<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>2</sub>)
>
> S<sub>n</sub> = 250(1 + 500)
>
> = 125250

Comment: It will also `return $total` which will break the loop.

Comment: *(hint)* Alt+0189 = ½ on Windows :) +1

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be...

```
$total = 0;
for ($i=1; $i<=500; $i++) {

 // echo $i . "<br />";

 $total = $total + $i;

}

echo $total . "<br />";
```

`return $total;` will break the loop

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're resetting `$total` to zero every time, and using `return` outside of a statement...

Anyways, the answer is `(500*501)/2 = 250*501 = 125250` (basic maths)

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors:

First, you set the `$total` to 0 each time the loop is repeated.

Then, you use `return`, what happens here is that it will cancel further execution, so the loop basically just was run once.

Try this.

```
$total = 0;
for ($i=1; $i<=500; $i++){
   $total = $total + $i;
}

echo $total;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$total = 0;

for ($i=1; $i<=500; $i++) {

    echo $i . ""; 
    $total = $total + $i; 

}

echo $total . "";
return $total;
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue